# Azure localisation - how to take resource files out of your packaged application?

Tags: azure, localization, globalization, resx

I have a localised site reading from your standard .resx resource files.  Everything works fine, however I am deploying to Azure.  The .resx files are packaged along with the rest of the site and deployed onto each role instance.  Meaning if I want to make a change to something I need to redeploy the entire package to Azure again and suffer a rolling update.

Is there a way I can get my site to read resource files from a single static location, such as blob storage?  Is this a good idea or should I just do my best to get it right first time?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well rolling updates aren't the end of the world. If your site is hosted with multiple running instances, each instance will be taken out of the load-balanced loop, brought down and updated in sequence, so your users shouldn't experience any real down time.

One option though would be to move to a non-resx based localization setup. you can write your own ResourceProvider to override the built in one. Rick Strahl had a nice example of reading resource information from a database.

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Apr/01/Updated-WestwindGlobalization-Data-Driven-Resource-Provider-for-ASPNET

Comment: No they aren't an impossible option, however some changes might need to be very small - like a tag for an advert needing updating.  Also one of our items in there I would like (at some point in the future) to be editable using a custom admin tool, but still kept in resources so that different cultures can have different content.  If I have to push the whole lot live then I have to do all this stuff myself and it isn't really ideal.  Is there no in-built Azure method?  The link you sent is pre the big Azure update...

Comment: But it still applies, you just have to adjust it to your needs.